# VB.Net Replace HTML Query

Tags: html, vb.net, replace

I'm having trouble replacing some HTML strings when they are coming from an database connection and was wondering if you could help.

```
html = Replace(html, "<ul>", "<ul class=""line"">")
```

The above line I'm using to replace all `<ul>` that I pull through with the preferred UL class. Problem is that all  tags are coming through as normal.

I use the above code to successfully replace the following and was wondering why it wouldn't do the same for `<ul>`.

```
html = Replace(html, "&lt;", "<")
html = Replace(html, "&gt;", ">")
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Drop this code

```
html = Replace(html, "&lt;", "<")
html = Replace(html, "&gt;", ">")
```

If you do that, this will display all the "<" and ">" as is, instead of interpreting them as tag delimiters.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to keep these in place due to a requirement from a system that puts information into the SQL tables.

Answer (score 0):

Decode the HTML first, then re-encode it:

```
Html = server.HtmlDecode(Html).Replace("<ul>", "<ul class=""line"">")
Html = Server.HtmlEncode(Html)
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but can I do these at the same time as my other html conversions?